# How to test ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, activeadmin, rspec-rails

I'm using ActiveAdmin on my rails project, and I would like to know how test it, like how does activeadmin usually test? Since there's no tutorial on the internet, is it necessary to test it?, like this answer I found https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256557/should-i-be-writing-feature-or-request-specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is built on Rails so use [Rails testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/testing.html). In particular I can recommend [Thoughtbot's approach](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications). Here is a typical feature spec using RSpec and Capybara:

```
feature City do
  scenario 'new city' do
    click_link 'Cities'
    click_link 'New City'
    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Wellington'
    click_button 'Create City'
    expect(page).to have_selector 'div.flash', text: 'City was successfully created.'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Example added to answer.

Comment: I answered here how to test, I answered the other question with why to test.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping!